# Show picture from database don´t work

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I wnt to show some pictures i have in a mysqli database, they are stored as blob.
But all i get is a A4 page with wierd text..

this is my code that i use too show(i connect to my database above this code):

```
echo "<table border=1>\n";
/*echo "  <tr>\n";
echo "    <th>Bild</th><th>Namn</th><th>Betygsättning</th>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";*/
while ($rad = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>";?> <img src="<?php echo $rad["Bild"]; ?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
      echo "<td>"; echo $rad["Namn"]; echo "</td>";   
      echo "</tr>";
}     
echo "</table>\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to embed the image to the generated html you should write it as this here:

```
echo "<td>";?> <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($rad["Bild"]); ?>" height="100" width="100"> <?php echo "</td>";
```

Here again with a little more clean code:

```
echo "<table border=\"1\">\n";
while($rad = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
    echo " <tr>\n";
    echo "  <td>\n";
    echo "   <img src=\"data:image/jpeg;base64," . base64_encode($rad["Bild"]) . "\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\" />\n";
    echo "  </td>\n";
    echo "  <td>" . $rad["Namn"] . "</td>";
    echo " </tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

It seem that you forgot also to close your img tag.

Comment: well that almost worked... all the wierd text is gone but the only thing is that i dont see the image.. :)

Comment: What is the real content type of the image? That could be the reason why it is not displayed. In my example I expected a jpeg image. For automatically filetype guessing you could use: http://php.net/function.finfo-file.php but I never used it.

Comment: it´s a jpeg yes, the other thing is that my footer disapeard.. after this code.. wierd..

Comment: Well I would start cleaning up your php code that mixing php with html leads to make trouble. I'll try to clean the code up for you.

Comment: Ok thx mate!!

If i only use this  echo "<td>"; echo $rad["Namn"]; echo "</td>";
I get the name from my database so it works.. its something with showing the image..

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works now and i can understad how it works!

I am most grateful! You have a good one now!!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<table border=1>';
/*echo "  <tr>\n";
echo "    <th>Bild</th><th>Namn</th><th>Betygsättning</th>\n";
echo "  </tr>\n";*/
while ($rad = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_result)) {
    echo '<tr>
            <td><img src="'.$rad["Bild"].'" height="100" width="100"></td>
            <td>'.$rad["Namn"].'</td>
          </tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

That should do it. While you are in a block of php code you can concatonate on it like above.